# I have a problem while running the kivy python application error in charset_normalize er and cchardet

Tags: python, android, kivy, logcat, kivymd

This is part of my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.animation import Animation
from arabic_reshaper import reshape
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import gtts
import time

class ScreenMain (Screen):
    pass
class Main (App):
    def build(self):
        pass

Main().run()
```

Converted to apk and tested on Android phone

But this error was showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
04-10 11:51:59.707  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 70, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.708  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/cchardet/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.709  5033  5115 I python  :  ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/cchardet/_cchardet.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)
04-10 11:51:59.709  5033  5115 I python  :  
04-10 11:51:59.709  5033  5115 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
04-10 11:51:59.710  5033  5115 I python  :  
04-10 11:51:59.710  5033  5115 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-10 11:51:59.710  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 13, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.711  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/openai/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.711  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/openai/api_resources/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.712  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/openai/api_resources/audio.py", line 4, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.713  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/openai/api_requestor.py", line 21, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.713  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.714  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/client.py", line 59, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.715  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 72, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.715  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/charset_normalizer/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.716  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/charset_normalizer/api.py", line 5, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.716  5033  5115 I python  :    File "/home/zyad/Desktop/kv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/charset_normalizer/cd.py", line 9, in <module>
04-10 11:51:59.717  5033  5115 I python  :  ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/charset_normalizer/md.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)
```

`
Is there a solution to this problem